# move char toward before printing in the console?

Tags: java

i am trying to find if there is method that can move the console printing some chars before printing ?

i try to print space and than delete but i didnt succeed.
example :
 excepted : " 5"
there is command that can do : ">" 
so next time when print "5" it will print " 5" .
 any Help ?

Comment: Could you please give some context to this? Perhaps the code you want to use this in?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't clear to me brother. But i think what you trying to do is print some spaces or anything for that matter in the console. Why don't you just modify the string before sout as you wish. 
example

```
System.out.println("    expected"+"   5");
```

If this isn't your problem ask me back the problem